# Determine a point in fiber is dicrete

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* by Qing Liu, page 133:[image]

I can figure out the first part. For the second part,we can assume $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec} B$, then $$X_y = X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k(y)=\operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_Bk(y))$$ $$=\operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_B B_{m_y}/m_yB_{m_y})=\operatorname{Spec}(A_{f^\#_x(m_y)}/f^\#_x(m_y)A_{f^\#_x(m_y)}).$$

Am I right till now? If I'm right, then we can use the first part and localize $A$ by some element $g$ so that $f^\#_x(m_y)A_g$ is a maximal ideal in $A_g$ and we are done. But I can't see how the condition '$f$ is of finite type' is used. So anyone can help me?

Comment: What does "$x$ is discrete in $X_y$" mean here? Most of the meanings I would imagine do not even hold in the very simple case of $\Bbb A^1_k\to\operatorname{Spec} k$ for some field $k$.

Comment: I think it means simply that "$x$ is open in $X_y$".And he requires moreover that $T_{f,x}$ is injective which fails in your case.

Comment: Ah, I had interpreted the statement of the problem as "$f$ finite type implies $x$ discrete in $X_y$" instead of "$f$ finite type and $T_{f,x}$ injective implies $x$ discrete in $X_y$. This would explain the issues.